web automation in python using selenium webdriver
Error:  Youtube opens and closes without executing the operations. Is there any way we can place chromedriver in selenium file or any other way out.
I tried this .:
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url='https://youtube.com'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

searchbox=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_keys("Google")

searchbutton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]/yt-icon/yt-icon-               shape/icon-shape/div')
searchbutton.click()

time.sleep(25)
driver.quit()


Open YouTube in Chrome and use the developer console (inspect element) to view the HTML. Hit CTRL+F to open the Find bar and enter the XPATH you're using for the search bar (//input[@id="search"]). You will see that that three elements are returned! The id of "search" is not unique. Selenium's find_element() returns the first element, which is NOT the search box. So in the XPATH you need to specify you're looking for an <input> element.
The other selector will not work either as-is. Here are correct locators:
searchbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_keys("Google")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'search-icon-legacy').click()


When you launch a browser using selenium, very likely you will get Accept/Reject cookies pop-up. Assuming you are getting this pop-up, here is the working code.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url='https://youtube.com'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label,'Accept')]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search']"))).send_keys("Google")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "search-icon-legacy"))).click()

time.sleep(25)
driver.quit()

